# Can FreeBSD be run inside Docker?

Tags: docker, freebsd

I have been looking for a `Docker` image of `FreeBSD` but cannot find, can FreeBSD be run inside docker? If not, why not?

Comment: Those ones don't work? (https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=freebsd&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0)

Comment: The person who submitted an answer says it needs a FreeBSD host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of caveats here but yes, you can and no its not depended on FreeBSD (but openbsd may not work).

```
#!/bin/sh

wget https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/ISO-IMAGES/13.2/FreeBSD-13.2-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso

cat -> docker-compose.yml <<< EOL
---
version: "3"
services:
    freebsd-via-qemu:
        image: jkz0/qemu:latest
        cap_add:
            - NET_ADMIN
        devices:
            - /dev/net/tun
            - /dev/kvm
        volumes:
            - ./FreeBSD-13.2-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso:/image
        restart: always
...
EOL
docker-compose up -d
```

The above shell script would download the boot only iso for FreeBSD then spin up a QEMU container which in turn boots the os. I do this with other systems like Plan9, SimH, MVS, Freenas, AROS, and VyOS. And yes this does work with Podman, WSL, or K8S too.

Now for the caveat here, this is clearly not a hypervisor running in Ring 0, but a x86 emulator running in user space and jailed off at that. Your not going to get any performance out of this setup and may see some issues with device drivers or worse just outright be unusable for anything other than as a toy/research.

Update:

Reliased I didn't answer OP's second question; the Why not. Docker at its fundamental is just a wrapper with a RestAPI daemon for core Linux kernel tech such as cgroup, NetNS, vxlans, proc namespaces, user namespaces, and unionfs. e.g. the bulk of what Plan9 has had since 1991 just redone by crunchy Linux Kernel devs.

Yes BSD has jails but that's userspace as a chroot not kernel space such as Linux or proc/stack space as Plan9. [This may have changed in Open or FreeBSD in the last 15 or so years]

Basically, a native bsd kernel or userspace inside a namespace stack of the Linux kernel space is not able to execute without an emulator or hypervisor. It's the same issue on WSL (aka hyper-v) and xhyve (OSx's hypervisor). This is why QEMU works in the example above. Its that hypervisor that loads a BSD kernel and operates within the container's namespace.

Comment: Amazing take. Love your approach even if it is just for research / fun!

Answer (score 19):

EDIT FROM THE FUTURE: No, you can't, none of the below projects ever went beyond prototypes.

---

Technically yes, but you need a FreeBSD host to do it and Docker is "somewhat unstable" on FreeBSD right now. There is a fork from Docker 1.7 that can technically launch containers, but nothing you would want to use for reals. Jetpack will hopefully be finalized for FreeBSD 11 and will provide a much better solution here.

https://wiki.freebsd.org/Docker has info. You can make it work on a fully updated 10.3 but expect lots of weirdness.

Comment: It is absolutely required that you have a FreeBSD host? Why ?

Comment: Because you can't run FreeBSD binaries on a Linux kernel/libc. Docker (and Jails, Zones, etc) just runs a process with lots of special flags, but at heart they need actually run.

Comment: The Docker FreeBSD port is not "*somewhat unstable*", it's outright unfinished. Virtualized networking, resource limits, volumes and links are not there. Furthermore, there hasn't been any activity for over 1.5 years. The project looks abandoned.

Comment: Many years ago it seemed like it might be a thing but both Docker on FreeBSD and Jetpack are now abandoned.

Comment: @Phil you can't because Linux and BSD using a different kernels like...totally. The only similarity between Linux and BSD are - they POSIX compliant and that's it.   Docker isn't a virtualization software like KVM, it only isolating processes by using underhold Linux kernel capabilities. That's why it's a pain to port docker to BSD, same as execute BSD application on non-BSD system.